# arduino - how to read and control the speed of a 12V - four wire fan?

Tags: arduino, fan

I want to read the rpm and control the speed of a 12V - four wire fan through Arduino. There are many articles describing the procedure, yet I have some questions.

**Read Speed:**

So, 12V and Gnd are connected to the who wires of the fan, and the third wire is connected to the Arduino's input pin through a pull-up resistor (internal or external), in order to read the pulses, thus the speed of the fan. I guess that it works like in the schematic below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT87he.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If so, how much is the voltage that the input pin reads when the sensor switch is closed, 5V ορ 12V? I believe that it is 12V, but that would damage the board, right? Should I put something like an optocoupler between fan and input pin, in order to isolate them?

**Control Speed**

Just about the same question for controlling the speed. Can I stick the fourth wire of the fan to a PWM pin? Is it true that the PWM pole of the fan accepts max.5.0V? Just to be on the safe side, should I use a motor driver IC, like L293D?

Thank you

Comment: The Arduino line would not be connected to a ground connection as you are showing.  To receive a better answer you should show the schematic of the whole fan circuit or provide a link to the spec sheet.

Comment: Your schematic is wrong. You have the input pin directly connected to ground: it will always read zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is the type of fan you are using:  http://www.formfactors.org/developer/specs/REV1_2_Public.pdf

-then the output sensor claims it is an open collector or open drain. (Meaning it only pulls down.) It also says "Motherboard will have a pull up to 12V, maximum 13.2V".  Written this way I would take this as a recommendation.  If the output is truly just an open collector/drain then you should be able to add your own pull-up resistor as needed.  For the Arduino input you would have the resistor pulled up to +5 only. (You could add the 5k resistor as shown, or if you know how to enable the internal pull-up on the Arduino port pin use that, in which case you would not need the 5k resistor shown.)  With a resistor in place the fan sensor pulls down (to 0v) then releases the pin, so it then climbs back up to what ever voltage the pull-up is connected too.

The hook up should look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fToTSf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But just as a precaution, before connecting the Arduino Speed input pin to Sense, you should measure the voltage on the Sense fan pin while the fan is slowly rotating (with 12v on the fan power input).

The spec lists the Fan's Control input to be a 5v PWM signal.  So coming from the Arduino no extra driver circuit is needed.

Also the spec says the pulses from the Sense pin is 2 per revolution, so measure the pulses per second then divide by 2.

Comment: Apologies for my poor schematic. Yes, the output sensor is open collector. I connected a 10kOhm pull-up resistor and it worked fine. Thank you.

Comment: 4-pin computer fans normally want the PWM signal to have a frequency of 25 KHz (acceptable range: 21 to 28 KHz) - https://folk.uio.no/kyrrens/diverse/viftekontroller/developer-specs-REV1_2_Public.pdf
Arduino's built-in PWM uses no more than 1 KHz (depending on the model) - https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/ It's possible, though, to directly set up the microcontroller's timer to generate a 25 KHz signal - https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/tylerpeppy/25-khz-4-pin-pwm-fan-control-with-arduino-uno-3005a1

Comment: The +5V pull-up for the fan connector's tach (sense) should work, although motherboards use +12V then step it down to an appropriate voltage with a voltage divider. This way if the fan's cable gets pinched and the power wire gets shorted to the tach (sense) wire, the motherboard's digital input will still see 3.3V (5V or 3.3V for Arduino, depending on the model) and not burn out

Comment: I've had some noise issues reading the tach signal while using PWM. More details in my comments in Michael Karas' answer.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the recommended way to connect up a typical four wire fan. I have used this design multiple times with good success.

The input signal here is a PWM signal of about 20 KHz frequency that controls the fan speed via the duty cycle. As shown the input signal was designed for a 3.3V swing signal but would also work for 5V swing. Most fans have a lower control range at about the 30% duty cycle range where they stop operating.

The output signal here is a 3.3V swing signal that is the tachometer signal from the fan. You measure the frequency of this signal to determine the fan speed. Note that fans vary and you will find fans that output two or four pulses per revolution on this output. If you need a 5V swing output from this output adjust the values of one of the two lower resistors in the divider.

[image]

The fan connection wire colors are typical but you may find some variations in the colors used by various manufacturers.

This circuit does several things that are important to consider. One this is that it isolates the on-board microcontroller from the voltage range used by the fan which can be important if there are ever faults or mistakes made in the fan wiring harness or connection. Secondly it provides an isolation in the case of static discharge.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the schematic. I successfully used it on a bread board. The only question I have is regarding the FAN_PWM pin.I used a 4.7K ohm as R251 and pulled to 3.3v instead of 5v. Seems to work but I don't know if it's ok before soldering...

Comment: @MikeGleasonjrCoitirier - You need to look at the fan spec to determine proper voltage swing for the PWM input. Using a reduced voltages may change the range of duty cycle control on some cheap fans.

Comment: What is the purpose of C228 capacitor?

Comment: Does this do anything for the tacho output?
My fan (Noctua) spec sheet mentions tacho is open collector output, pull-up Vcc: 13V. I'm guessing it's a max value. Can we pull up the tacho output to 5V instead of 12V? If yes, would the two resistors R248 and R249 still be necessary, or could they be removed or replaced with a single resistor? I have this seemingly working on a breadboard (3.3K pull-up to 5V, 10K for R248, then going to an Arduino's input). I'm counting interrupts on that pin, it works as described. If I remove R248, I'm getting only noise.

Comment: @GenePavlovsky - C228 is a bulk power supply bypass capacitor to supply current surges that may happen when the fan starts and stops. R247, R248 and R249 are designed to allow the swing of the TACH output of the fan to be maximized around the open drain/collector output of the fan get better signal to noise isolation whilst a the same time reducing the output to a 3.3V swing for feeding into the device that monitors the TACH signal.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Thanks for a very detailed explanation. I've also read somewhere that a good reason to pull the TACH output to 12V rather than 5V (or 3.3V), then stepping it down with a voltage divider, is to provide safety in the event the fan's cable gets pinched and the power and tach wire short. The tach signal would be wrong but the mobo wouldn't be fried.

Comment: I was experimenting with hooking up the fan as per this circuit diagram (and also, as my fan is from Noctua, the much more primitive diagram in Noctua PWM white paper), to an Arduino Uno. I also connected the fan's PWM input to an output pin on the Arduino, and set this up to control the fan's speed (PWM at 25 KHz) via a potentiometer. I was having some trouble with reading the TACH signal via an interrupt. It was working correctly at 0% and 100% duty cycle, but erroneous readings (~30000 RPM) at all other RPMs. Seems like 25 KHz PWM signal was inducing noise in the TACH wire.

Comment: For some reason, code that used Arduino's pulseIn function to measure the time between TACH pulses, was not affected, and worked correctly. I played with it for a while, adding a capacitor here or there, until accidentally one wire I temporarily disconnected from the breadboard, touched an exposed section of the 12V power wire, letting the magic smoke out of the Arduino.
Unfortunately I don't own an oscilloscope yet so I couldn't really see what sort of noise I was getting on the TACH output.

Comment: Since you mentioned you've used this design multiple times, have you ever experienced issues like I described? If so, what did you do to solve them? I've heard suggestions of an RC filter (didn't succeed with that), a Schmitt trigger (haven't tried), software debouncing (tried rejecting interrupts which happen too soon after a previous interrupt, it partially helped if I also had a 100nf capacitor between ground and the point between R247 and R248 - there were about 12-15 such spurious interrupt for each initial one / each pulse).

Comment: @GenePavlovsky - I have never had problems like you describe. The circuit as shown is designed to isolate the fan from the control circuitry both from an ESD perspective and and from a fan wiring/connection problems. Yes shorted wiring from the 12V lead can mess with the TACH input to the circuit and this is indeed another reason that this circuit uses voltage divider from TACH. Some noise filtering with a small capacitor in parallel with R249 is possible but I've not seen it necessary in most cases. This circuit design has been in use on my projects and on Intel (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) Server Board Reference designs since I introduced it about 15 years ago. As far as using an interrupt to detect the TACH you want to have either an edge triggered interrupt or setup to get a low/high and then in the ISR immediately reconfigure the interrupt trigger for high/low detection. If you just have a simple level sensitive interrupt you could very well be triggering the interrupt over and over dozens of times whilst the TACH signal is at its active low or high input level.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Thanks! I've tried various settings for Arduino's attachInterrupt function - RISING, FALLING, CHANGE. All three of these are supposed to trigger only when the state of the pin changes. But yeah, the way it was actually triggering is similar to what you describe, I don't know why would it do like that, though. I'm going to get an oscilloscope with my next salary, and see how that signal actually looks like. (continued)

Comment: It's just a guess, but since I had everything set up on a breadboard, with Dupont male-male wires for connections, perhaps the PWM wire was acting as an RF transmitter antenna, and the TACH wire was receiving this, adding a lot of noise to the signal. Maybe if I just soldered the same circuit on a protoboard, the issue would go away. That's something else I will try after I get an oscilloscope (want to investigate on the breadboard first).

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly the first question:**

Please specify what you will be using as switch. Maybe an optical sensor with an encoder? Or maybe a transmitter and receiver infrared leds? Or even a magnetic, inductive or capacitive sensor? Assuming you already have an efficient way to count the pulses it's very important to feed the switch with 5V (the limit for arduino). Also, your resistor is misplaced. You can put it between the Arduino input and the ground or input and Vcc, but for this you will need to also move the switch to between the gnd and input. Look for your circuit, when the switch is open you will have 0V on input. When it closes, you will have 0V too, so it doesn't works. Since the switch probably is not an inductive load you will not need the optocoupler.

**How to control**

Except you will need also to feed another fan and need to do reversion, I will not recommend a motor driver for cost reason. If you are worried with only the speed, you can use a simple transistor to do the job. Just remember the maximum current Arduino can output is 40mA (if you are not using a modified one). Also you need to establish the maximum current you will want at the fan to verify the *hfe* of transistor to make sure it will have enough gain. Since it is a 12 V fan I believe it will not be a real worry.

**Finally**

Try to better explain your project, I really found it very confusing, but tried to answer with what you gave me.

Comment: I think the OP meant the SW1 to be the virtual "switch" (actually hall sensor, open drain/collector) inside the fan. For controlling the fan's speed, you don't need a transistor since 4-pin fans accept a digital PWM signal, the control circuitry is inside the fan